# Power by normal force

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, power

Would the power created by the normal force always be zero? Since normal force is always perpendicular to the object?

Comment: It doesn't matter if the force is perpendicular _to the object itself_, but rather if it is perpendicular _to the motion of the object_. Please edit the question to make it more clear what you mean.

Answer (score 4):

No, for instance, if you are in an elevator the normal force is making work on you, increasing your gravitational potential energy

Answer (score 1):

Normal force is always perpendicular to the the surface of contact  and  for fixed surfaces an object has its velocity directed  along the surface hence angle between the two vectors is zero and pwer developed = 0. But it's hink of a case in which the surface also moves relative to ground then the velocity of the object with respect to ground may  not perpendicular to the normal force hence  it's power may or may not be zero